# Casting a int to a pointer?

Tags: go

in C/C++ I can cast `int` to a `int*` like this

```
int i = 0x1040c108;
int *p = (int*)i; // compiles
```

but why can't I do this in Go?

```
addr := 0x1040c108
p := (*int)(addr) // Error: cannot convert addr (type int) to type *int
```

What is the way to achieve this in golang ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go through the unsafe package. Please note that it is called "unsafe" for a reason and probably shouldn't be used unless you REALLY need to do operations that bypass type safeties, or operate on memory directly.

https://play.golang.org/p/WUavNAlyVP

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    var intaddr int = 0x1040c108
    var addr uintptr = uintptr(intaddr)
    ptr := unsafe.Pointer(addr)
    p := (*int)(ptr)
    fmt.Printf("Type: %T, Ptr: %v, Val: %d", p, p, *p)
}
```

Comment: considering what this package is doing I'm kind of amazed that this code is allowed in something like the golang playground

Comment: @JasonSperske Yeah, no kidding. They've gotta trust their sandbox quite a bit.

Comment: Apparently they have put a lot of thought into this https://blog.golang.org/playground fascinating stuff :)